# Формирование печатных форм документов УПД/ТОРГ12/ТТН в PDF на GOLANG

Tags: html, golang, pdf

Требуется сформировать такие документы, как УПД, ТОРГ-12 или Справка к ТТН/ГТД.

Для формирования PDF файлов использую шаблон в HTML и утилиту [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org) вкупе с [go-wkhtmltopdf](http://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf)

Утилита отлично справляется с простыми отчётами и печатными формами, но с вышеуказанными документами возникают проблемы (высокая сложность HTML шаблона, огромные риски поправить одно и сломать другое)

Есть какие-либо альтернативы для формирования сложных документов используя GOLANG или положительный опыт использования данного инструментария?